# Why cant I make post request to my server in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON file that store my data.I can react to data from store and there is no problem in connecting to server.My problem is when i make post request,it fire error.I controlled the link again and again, but couldnt find the error. I opened it in server **'http://localhost:8000/cars'**.This is my store.

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "name": "Bmw 418d",
      "img": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/02/12/25/bmw-918408_960_720.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.arabalar.com.tr/bmw/4-serisi/2018/418d-2-0-gran-coupe",
      "order": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mazda CX-3",
      "img": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/18/17/16/mazda-mx5-3546782_960_720.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.arabalar.com.tr/mazda/cx-3/2017/1-5-sky-d-motion",
      "order": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Volvo S60",
      "img": "https://www.arabahabercisi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Volvo-Cars-Hibrit-Modeller-Geliyor.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.arabalar.com.tr/volvo/s60/2018/1-5-t3-advance",
      "order": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Skoda Superb",
      "img": "https://www.arabateknikbilgi.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ArabaTeknikBilgi-2017-Skoda-Superb.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.arabalar.com.tr/skoda/superb/2018/1-4-tsi-active",
      "order": "4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Honda Civic",
      "img": "https://www.autogreeknews.gr/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/honda-civic-type-r-sport-line-price-2.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.arabalar.com.tr/honda/civic/2018/1-6-elegance",
      "order": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also a function that make post request. But i take error **POST http://localhost:8000/cars 500 (Internal Server Error)**. This is my **Create** function that make post request

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Create = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [link, setLink] = useState('');
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const cars = {name,link};

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/cars',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(cars)
    }).then(() => {
      // history.go(-1);
      history.push('/');
    })
  }

  return (

    <form action="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="name-group">
        <label>Name of Car</label>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          value={name}
          type="text"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="link-group">
        <label>Car picture link</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setLink(e.target.value)}
          value={link}
        />
      </div>
      <button>Add Car</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Create;
```

Comment: Instead of using localhost you have to use local ip address

Comment: Because  I did it before the same way.But here I couldnt find the error. https://github.com/sayinmehmet47/carAppWithReact. Look the code completely here

Comment: So how can I get ip adress?

Comment: you need to configure a server that listens to your localhost. `ngrok` can help you here

Comment: I did it with npx json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000

Comment: I am listening the server but as you can see in github link

Comment: type ipconfig in cmd you will get the local ip address of your system. Then use the url like this 'http://your_local_ip:8000/cars'. Make sure that server is running

Comment: some folk are saying that installing `loadash` solved their problem https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/303

Comment: I tried loadash but it didnt work

Comment: Go to chrome devtools and open the network tab and paste what the log says about the POST request.

Comment: I dont know if I am sending wrong type of data. It is in object and stored in cars. I input the data end send it to server. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcRFYF4B3IQ&t=215s   look at 3.35

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Function.createId (C:\Users\mehmet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\13008\node_modules\json-server\lib\server\mixins.js:58:39)
    at Function.insert (C:\Users\mehmet\AppData\Roaming\npm-